# How can I display the name of the month in different languages in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: localization, text-formatting, google-sheets

In Microsoft Excel the following formula forces the month name to be displayed in Portuguese, regardless of the default language.

`=TEXT(A1,"[$-pt-PT] dd mmmm yyyy")`

Google Spreadsheets ignores the parameter `[$-pt-PT]`. How can I format dates to different language than the default on in Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: Very good point and use case that Google Sheets doesn't seem to support at the moment. For a bit of context, I'm sending recruitment appointment emails with dates in different languages. I use Sheets in English, but need weekdays in French and German.

Answer (score 9):

1. Dates are displayed based not on the browser default language, but on the spreadsheet locale, which is set in File > Spreadsheet options.
2. You can also use the =GOOGLETRANSLATE() formula.

Comment: Well the purpose of the question is to have multiple languages, right? So 1st point is out of the window. The 2nd is an okay idea, but it's a just such a shame google sheets ignores that parameter

Comment: Was that indeed the purpose of the question? Just reading it is a little unclear what default you had in mind when you wrote "different language than the default on in Google Spreadsheets". I would say it's quite an improbable requirement to have multiple language date formats in the same spreadsheet.

Comment: @ttarchala: No, I'm having this exact same use case. Marketing emails with dates in different languages. I use everything in English, but need weekdays in French and German.

Answer (score 3):

Since `text` does not support language parameter, this seems to require manual "translation". I would put the Portuguese month names somewhere in the spreadsheet (they could be on another, hidden sheet) and use the following:

```
=text(A5,"dd ") & index(S1:S12, month(A5)) & text(A5, " yyyy")
```

Here S1:S12 is the range in which the month names are contained. The `index` picks the correct month based on the date, which is concatenated to the rest of the date.

Comment: That is how I am doing it at the moment, but I really wanted to do it better.